# Wordpress - Is it possible to display posts within a seperate directory to the pages?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a website using WordPress and am wondering if its possible to display posts and the archives of posts (IE /2010/09 etc.) in a seperate directory to the rest of the site.

Example:
domain.com/blog/this-is-a-blog-post
domain.com/blog/2010/09/
domain.com/about-us
domain.com/products

Does anyone know if this is possible, or has done this before or point me somewhere that has, I'd be super appreciative.

Comment: Oooh, no, I hadn't, I shall give that a shot tomorrow, was kind of hoping there was a way to do it in WordPress though so the Caretakers can change it themselves.

Comment: So, apparently I don't know Mod_rewrite code well enough to get it to stop conflicting with the rules and conditions set in the .htaccess by WordPress itself. And I don't have time to learn it properly.

Comment: Also the fact that from what I can work out, this would be displaying the content FROM:  
'domain.com/blog/this-is-a-post' 

but we need it to be displaying the content for: 
'domain/this-is-a-post'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it can be done with a mixture of mod-rewrite and using a few pieces from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index